# JS : Remove duplicated values from specific string in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my array lists :

```
['<h3>Goalkeepers</h3><a href="#" data-id="44">Lewis Cardiff City &pound;4.00</a>',
'<h3>Goalkeepers</h3><a href="#" data-id="42">Given Aston Villa &pound;4.00</a>',
'<h3>Goalkeepers</h3><a href="#" data-id="36">Robles Everton &pound;4.30</a>']
```

I want to remove duplicate values which only contains between `'<h3></h3>'` tags.

my expectation will be somthing like this:

```
['<h3>Goalkeepers</h3><a href="#" data-id="44">Lewis Cardiff City &pound;4.00</a>',
'<a href="#" data-id="42">Given Aston Villa &pound;4.00</a>',
'<a href="#" data-id="36">Robles Everton &pound;4.30</a>']
```

Tried .reduce , .map, .filter method to solve this issue. but no luck.
someone please help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: So the wanted `h3` is always in the first element of the array?

Comment: That's right. <h3> will be always in the first elem of the array. but not rest of elements.

Comment: How have you tried `reduce` and `map`? Show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer:

```
    function removeDuplicates(a) {
        var first = null;
        return a.map(function(item) {
            var h3 = item.match(/^<h3>([^<]+)<\/h3>/);
            if(first && first === h3[1]) return item.slice(h3[0].length);
            else {
                first = h3[1];
                return item;
            }
        });   
    }
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/WA8DE/ .
You can see an interesting side effect there (in browser's console) - the code will remove any subsequent duplicates in the array ("Shoplifters").

But please note that this is not the best way to structure and process your data. 
It would be much more convenient to have it structured like this:

```
    var data = {
        Goalkeepers: [
            {url: '#', id: 44, name: "Lewis Cardiff City", bribe: 4.00},
            {url: '#', id: 42, name: "Given Aston Villa", bribe: 4.00},
            {url: '#', id: 46, name: "Robles Everton", bribe: 4.00},
        ],
        Shoplifters: [
            // ...
        ],
        // etc.
    };
```

This can be retrieved from your server as JSON and used almost directly with the help of `JSON.parse()`. You can also generate this kind of structure from any other data.

And then, produce HTML when it has to be rendered on your web page. Something like:

```
    function dataToHTML(d) {
        var out = "";
        for(var section in data) {
            if(!data.hasOwnProperty(section)) continue;
            out += "<h3>" + section + "</h3>";
            out += data[section].map(function(item){
                return "<a href=\"" + item.url + "\" data-id=\"" + item.id + "\">" + item.name + " &pound;" + item.bribe + "</a>";
            }).join('');
        }
        return out;
    }

    dataToHTML(data); // -> HTML string
```

But then, this looks almost like a crude template, so you'd probably need something more elegant, like underscore templates: http://underscorejs.org/#template .

Program with data, not strings ;)

Comment: Thanks nooga!. really appreciate it

Comment: From your latest codes , I have a following error : 
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'map'

because, data is object. not an array?

Answer (score 0):

## Simple way

```js
const arr = ["red","pink","pink","green","yellow","red","blue",];
console.log([...new Set(arr)]);
```